# How does this custom service work/ update data?

Tags: angularjs, caching, angular-ui-router

I wrote a service that should populate data with a call to the server the first time, but then keep it in memory and return that consequent times. Because I want to use it also in ui-Router, it should return a promise.

This is the service:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("common.services")
    .service("dataCache", ["tabResource", "fieldResource", "$q", "$http", dataCache]);

function dataCache(tabResource, fieldResource, $q, $http) {
    var self = this;
    self.tabs = null;

    var getTabs = function () {
        // create deferred operation
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (self.tabs !== null) {
            toastr.warning("tabs from cache");
            deferred.resolve(self.tabs);
        } else {
            // get the data from the server
            $http.get('http://localhost:40000/api/tab')
                .then(function(response) {
                    self.tabs = response.data;
                    deferred.resolve(self.tabs);
                    toastr.warning("tabs from server");
                }, function (response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });

        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        tabs: getTabs()
    };
}
}());
```

And these are the different states where 'tabs' are used:

```
                .state("relationCustom", {
                url: "/relations/customisation",
                templateUrl: "webApp/relations/relationCustomView.html",
                controller: "RelationCustomCtrl as vm",
                resolve: {
                    tabResource: "tabResource",
                    fieldResource: "fieldResource",
                    // tabs: function (tabResource) {
                    //    return tabResource.query({}, function () { toastr.success('Tabs geladen...'), function () { toastr.error('Tabs laden MISLUKT!') } }).$promise;
                    //}
                    tabs: function (dataCache) {
                        return dataCache.tabs;
                    }
                    , fields: function (fieldResource) {
                        return fieldResource.query({}, function () { toastr.success('Velden geladen...'), function () { toastr.error('Tabs laden MISLUKT!') } }).$promise;
                    }
                }
            })
            .state("relationDetailTab", {
                url: "/relations/:customerName/:relId/:tabId",
                templateUrl: "webApp/relations/relationDetailTabView.html",
                controller: "RelationDetailTabCtrl as vm"
                ,
                resolve: {
                    relationTabResource: "relationTabResource",
                    relationTab: function (relationTabResource, $stateParams) {
                        var relId = $stateParams.relId;
                        var tabId = $stateParams.tabId;
                        return relationTabResource.query({ id: relId, id2: tabId }).$promise;   // query expects array <-> get expects object
                    }
                    //, tabs: function (tabResource, dataCache) {
                    //    return tabResource.query({}, function () { toastr.success('Tabs geladen...'), function () { toastr.error('Tabs laden MISLUKT!') } }).$promise;
                    //}
                    , tabs: function (dataCache) {
                        return dataCache.tabs;
                    }
                    , fields: function (fieldResource, dataCache) {
                        return fieldResource.query({}, function () { toastr.success('Velden geladen...'), function () { toastr.error('Tabs laden MISLUKT!') } }).$promise;
                    }
                }
            })
            .state("relationDetailTabEdit", {
                url: "/relations/:customerName/:relId/:tabId/edit",
                templateUrl: "webApp/relations/relationDetailTabEditView.html",
                controller: "RelationDetailTabEditCtrl as vm",
                resolve: {
                    relationTabResource: "relationTabResource",
                    relationTab: function (relationTabResource, $stateParams) {
                        var relId = $stateParams.relId;
                        var tabId = $stateParams.tabId;
                        return relationTabResource.query({ id: relId, id2: tabId }).$promise;   // query expects array <-> get expects object
                    }
                    //, tabs: function (tabResource) {
                    //    return tabResource.query({}, function () { toastr.success('Tabs geladen...'), function () { toastr.error('Tabs laden MISLUKT!') } }).$promise;
                    //}
                    , tabs: function (dataCache) {
                        return dataCache.tabs;
                    }
                    , fields: function (fieldResource) {
                        return fieldResource.query({}, function () { toastr.success('Velden geladen...'), function () { toastr.error('Tabs laden MISLUKT!') } }).$promise;
                    }
                }
            });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");   // Default route
    }]);
```

I did put breakpoints on various lines in the code of the service and it only enters the code when the application is loaded the first time. When I go to another state, none of the code of the service seems to be executed. Can anybody explain me why? But even stranger, when I save a new tab to the server, it automatically appears in the 'tabs' in other states, apparently(according to fiddler) without the service calling back to the server. I am happy it all works, but would really like to understand how...

Comment: `I don't seem to enter the code` isn't clear what the specific problem is

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear at all. I edited the text. Problem is that I do not understand how it is possible that the code of the function in the service is only executed once, while it should be executed for every change of state.

Comment: Still not clear. You do realize that `return dataCache.tabs;` does not invoke the function?

Comment: No, I didn't. Thanks for helping me on my way! Now that I am actually calling the function, I found some other errors and the way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it wasn't an angular question, but a javascript one. With the help of the comments I solved the problem.

Changes in the code of the service:

```
return {
    tabs: getTabs
};
```

Changes in the states:

```
tabs: function (dataCache) {
                    return dataCache.tabs();
                }
```

This way, the function is actually called in the resolve block of the state